# KVM Switch for desktop (hdmi+usb connection) + laptop (usb-c connection)

Tags: kvm-switch, usb-c, docking-station

I would like to set up my home workstation (desktop tower, 1 monitor, mouse, keyboard) so that a KVM switch can be used so that a laptop can easily use the monitor, mouse and keyboard. It appears the KVM switches are all set up so that the computer input is either HDMI+usb input or usb-c input. My daughter's school issued chromebook does not have an HDMI port. What is the solution to connecting the two computers to the KVM switch? Do I need to connect a docking station to the KVM switch, and the laptop to the docking station?

Comment: Did you ever find something like this?

Answer (score 0):

Check if chromebook is able to display 2nd monitor, via USB-c.  If so buy an USB-C to HDMI(female) adapter, or direct cable USB-C-to HDMI.  I presume there is also no VGA port on the laptop.
Other option is docking station if you have it, but many new docking stations use connection via USB-c anyways.